# Unity Cross Platform InApp Purchase Service

Tags: in-app-billing, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I am having hard time working with Unity's cross platform GooglePlay InApp purchase service.
I am pasting the link below from which what I have been following for my implementation.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAPProcessingPurchases.html

The problem is:

```
public PurchaseProcessingResult ProcessPurchase(PurchaseEventArgs args) {}
```

This method is called every time. Every time what I mean is, Even if there is no internet connection, this function is called and returning PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete. I am wondering and no clue where I should unlock the locked items after successfull purchase. If this function is called even if there is no internect connection, I don't know what to say.... In demo, I saw unlock logic in this particular method after checking product id.

Could someone guide me the proper implementation with receipt validation for google play. I tested the same logic in Apple, and it seems to be working fine.

The problem is with the Google store. Please someone guide me for the right implementation.

I am following the same implementation what suggested in this link:
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game
Have a look at the attached screenshot. You can see google native inapp popping out and at the same time, onPurchaseFailed function is called. That's how I am showing the Purchase Error dialog. You can see that in action behind google native inapp dialog. And at the same time, ProcessPurchase is also called.

BTW, this behaviour is random. 70% of the time, I am getting google inapp native popup and transaction is successful most of the time. Its working as expected most of the time. But both ProcessPurchase and OnPurchaseFailed is also called occasionally. This random behaviour suggests that there must be something wrong in Unity IAP module or its behaviour is not consistent in all android devices.....
Don't get confused by google account verification error in native dialog. Its the same case with my other valid accounts too....

[image]

Comment: Unity uses a centralized handler to manage IAP in any platform. So if your iOS code works it should work in Android as well. However the quality of the question is very poor. You should add code or pictures to let us help you... Follow this tutorial -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLmwpz5JAwY

Comment: Hi Cabrra, updated my question. I didn't put code there cos Its the one I copied from the link I pasted there. You can take a look at the screenshot and my comments added in original question

Comment: and when it occurs, this is the message it throws "PurchaseFailureReason.ExistingPurchasePending"

Comment: After some research I narrowed your problem. 1- verify your credit card 2- wait 1 to 3 days 3- if none of before works try this -> http://www.androidgadgematic.com/2012/10/fix-google-play-store-we-are-unable-to-verify-your-account.html
     Thanks.

Comment: Cabrra, thats why I mentioned "Don't get confused by google account verification error in native dialog. Its the same case with my other valid accounts too...." as the last statement in my question... Its working with valid cards but occasionally, it's throwing OnPurchaseFailed and ProcessPurchase function call at the same time

Comment: I understand your concern. My last suggestion is to contact Unity help center. I did it before and they are really nice. Sorry for not being able to help you but without the code or anything else there isn't much to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found answer for my own question...

I was triggering inapp purchase call twice concurrently.

In unity, I accidently placed one button below the other. It was the one triggering IAP call twice... After removing that, everything started working fine....

I am having another issue, Out of 8 NON CONSUMABLES and 4 CONSUMABLES, two consumables are acting as non consumables.... Any Idea ???

Update:
   Those 2 items were declared as non consumables and made a purchase too before changing them to consumables. This was the reason for that unsual behaviour. Now everything is working fine.